# Solving T(n) = 4T(n/2) + theta(n^2 / logn)

Tags: big-o, master-theorem

I am trying to solve

> T(n) = 4T(n/2) + theta(n^2 / logn)

I want to use the `Master` Method but am unsure how to prove

> n^2 >> (n^2 log^-1n)

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: look at the limit of `n^2 / (n^2 / logn)`.

Comment: Maybe this question should be asked on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com).